# Как остановить setInterval для всех each кроме одного?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как остановить уже выполняющиеся setInterval кроме активного?
Скрипт выполняет анимацию чата, всплывание сообщений, при переключении таба анимация начинается заново, нужно остановить уже начатые.

```js
// Tabs
$(".tabgroup > div, .tabgroup .massage").hide();
$(".tabs a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this),
    tabgroup = '#' + $this.parents('.tabs').data('tabgroup'),
    others = $this.closest('li').siblings().children('a'),
    target = $this.attr('href');
  others.removeClass('active');
  $this.addClass('active');
  $(tabgroup).children('div').hide().removeClass("active");
  $(tabgroup).find(".massage").hide();
  $(target).show().addClass("active");
  $(target).each(function() {
    // Show massage
    var tik,
      i = 0,
      massage = $(target).find(".massage"),
      massageLength = massage.length;
    tik = setInterval(function() {
      if (i < massageLength) {
        $(massage[i]).fadeIn(500);
        i++;
        $(".massageList, .custom-scroll_inner").animate({
          scrollTop: 9999
        }, 1000);
      } else {
        clearInterval(tik);
      }
    }, 2000);
  });

});
// Auto show first
$(".tabs li:first-of-type a").click();
```

Comment: а зачем `setInterval` тут вообще?

Comment: Присоединяюсь? Для более точного ответа, выложите часть кода, с которым можно полноценно поиграться.

Comment: SetInterval по очереди показывает скрытые блоки (сообщения).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам нужно [это](https://api.jquery.com/stop/):

```
$(".massageList, .custom-scroll_inner").stop( true, true ).animate(...)
```

Первый параметр очищает очередь анимаций.
Второй переводит элемент в конечное состояние.